# Getting Error: "underlying connection closed: unexpected error on request receive"

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, oracle

I am using .Net application with web service(.net) and oracle database. But when i send some request to the server and waiting for the result it is giving following error

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred

I am unable to get the cause of the error. Can any one plese help me to get actual cause of this error and what i need to do solution. This errror occurce only in Production Server. Same code in Dev and Test server it is working.

Comment: Check if the database is running and is accessible from .Net Accplicatoin, the connection string is corret. Also put more information about the error, looking for innerexception.

Comment: Check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915599) article.

Comment: It runs properly till 5 mins... if the request exceed 5 mins it will get this error

Comment: Check the number of active connections to database server, may be you are not closing them, on production as usage is high this is causing problem

Comment: How to check this?? I dont have access also in PRO server

Comment: Can you provide the inner exception and stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the error inside web service method or function that you are calling. Just create proper error handling and log web service exception. Here is my sample code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void MyServerMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            //open connection and execute your calls to Oracle DB...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogServiceException(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    void LogServiceException(Exception ex)
    {
        string fullMessage = ex.Message;
        while (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            ex = ex.InnerException;
            fullMessage += " Inner exception: " + ex.Message;
        }
        //log your exception to log file, DB or eventlog...
        //in this case I will use log file, just make sure you appropriate filesystem rights to do this...
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("LogFile.txt", fullMessage);
    }
```